# Show that function is not linear

Tags: linear-algebra

The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies

- $f(1,1,0)=-1$
- $f(-1,1,1)=1$
- $f(1,-1,-1)=1$

Show that it cannot be linear.

One option is to argue that if it was linear, then
$$
f(0)=f((-1,1,1)+(1,-1,-1))=f(-1,1,1)+f(1,-1,-1)=2
$$
but a linear function needs to satisfy $f(0)=0$.

Is also a valid argument to
consider the system
$$
\begin{align*}
x+y&=-1\\
-x+y+z&=1\\
x-y-z&=1
\end{align*}
$$
that is, write down the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 &-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and to show that this has no solution?

I think not, it does not make sense to do that.

Comment: What's the sense for the construction of your Linear System Equations? The first part is  ok.

Comment: That is my point exactly. I found this as a solution in an exam and do not understand.

Comment: Seems contradiction method: suppose that $f$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: But why does the system of linear equations (and that it has no solution) show that it cannot be linear?

Comment: To construct a linear transformation using information about the images, you need to know how $f $affects the basis vectors. Clearly set $S=\{(1,1,0),(-1,1,1),(1,-1,-1)\}=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$, is not a basis (there are three vectors but they are not linearly independent). Now, the problem is not that $B$ is not a basis, the problem is that the equations present a clear contradiction. Therefore such a linear transformation cannot exist. About your second question, I think it is not practical but the idea is that $f(v_1)=x, f(v_2)=y$ and $f(v_3)=z$, then method of contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(1,0,0)=x$, $f(0,1,0)=y$ and $f(0,0,1)=z$. Assuming that $f$ is linear, $f$ is completely determined by the values of $x,y,z\in\mathbb R$, because $$f(a,b,c)=af(1,0,0)+bf(0,1,0)+cf(0,0,1)=ax+by+cz.$$
Applying that to the given equations yields the linear system you mention. If we show that this system has no solution, then there cannot be a linear function satisfying the given equations.

Comment: So you would say that the argument is valid?

Comment: Yes, if one gives some justification why it is valid, as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is linear. By 2nd equation and linearity, we must have that $f(1, -1, -1) = -1 f(-1, 1, 1) = -1$, but that contradicts the 3rd equation.

Comment: I do not see what $x, y$ and $z$ are supposed to mean here and why the  given information about the function determines the system of linear equations.

Comment: @Rhjg Ok, what's the definition of linearity of the function $f$?